# Scala - Get all months and days for a given year

Tags: scala, date, calendar

I need to create a function that return the sequence of all days for a given year as string date triples (year, month, day).

```
def allDaysForYear(year: String) = {
 ...// get every month and day for that $year

  }
```

Then I will use in this way:

```
for ((year, month, day) <- allDaysForYear("2017"))
        yield doSomethingElse(p(year), p(month), p(day))
```

In my attempts I used Calendar Object and Iterator[Calendar], but did not managed to have a clean and small code.

This does not seem complicated to archive, perhaps someone has a better idea on how to handle dates.

What is the most efficient way to perform this in Scala?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this with a simple for comprehension and the `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.Year`:

```
    import java.time.{LocalDate, Year}

    def allDaysForYear(year: String): List[(String, String, String)] = {
      val daysInYear = if(Year.of(year.toInt).isLeap) 366 else 365
      for {
        day <- (1 to daysInYear).toList
        localDate = LocalDate.ofYearDay(year.toInt, day)
        month = localDate.getMonthValue
        dayOfMonth = localDate.getDayOfMonth
      } yield (year, month.toString, dayOfMonth.toString)
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for leap years - e.g. for 2016, 31 Dec is missing.

Comment: See updated code (now taking into account leap years, needed to add another java.time import)

Comment: That rocks in case java 1.8 is installed, what if is a lower version? In that case `import java.time` is not available, what can be used instead?

Comment: I see you created another question pointing out this requirement - see the answer I posted for that Q using Joda-Time. Joda-Time is essentially the java.time package before it was created in 1.8: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261011/scala-get-list-of-days-and-months-for-a-selected-year

Answer (score 0):

Use [Lamma Date](http://lamma.io)

```
Date(2015, 1, 1) to Date(2015, 12, 131) foreach println 

Date(2015,1,1)
Date(2015,1,2)
Date(2015,1,3)
Date(2015,1,4)
```