# Scala - Get list of days and months for a selected year

Tags: scala, calendar

I asked a question regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247605/scala-get-all-months-and-days-for-a-given-year/44247967#44247967). It works fine and is a nice solution, however I just realized that in some cases when java 1.8 is NOT installed `import java.time` is not available. I have java 1.7 and cannot update due many other issues.

**after java 1.8**

```
import java.time.{LocalDate, Year}

def allDaysForYear(year: String): List[(String, String, String)] = {
  val daysInYear = if(Year.of(year.toInt).isLeap) 366 else 365
  for {
    day <- (1 to daysInYear).toList
    localDate = LocalDate.ofYearDay(year.toInt, day)
    month = localDate.getMonthValue
    dayOfMonth = localDate.getDayOfMonth
  } yield (year, month.toString, dayOfMonth.toString)
}
```

**older java versions:**

so, for instance using `import java.util.{Calendar}` how can the same issue be solved? -> **Get all months and days for a given year**

Comment: check out joda-time for a similar library to java-8 time (same author). http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: It does, they are just named slightly differently. Read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Joda-Time, the following worked for me:

```
import java.util.Calendar
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, LocalDate, DurationFieldType}

def allDaysForYear(year: String): List[(String, String, String)] = {
  val dateTime = new DateTime()
  val daysInYear = if(dateTime.withYear(year.toInt).year.isLeap) 366 else 365
  val calendar = Calendar.getInstance
  calendar.set(year.toInt, 0, 0)
  val ld = LocalDate.fromCalendarFields(calendar)
  for {
    day <- (1 to daysInYear).toList
    updatedLd = ld.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days, day)
  } yield (year, updatedLd.getMonthOfYear.toString, updatedLd.getDayOfMonth.toString)
}
```